# JLayeredPane versus Container layering

Tags: java, swing

[JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) allows one to stack multiple Components on top of one another using [JLayeredPane.add(Component, Integer)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29). Components in higher "layers" display on top of Components in lower "layers".

[Container.add(Component, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) provides a similar mechanism whereby Components with **lower** indexes display on top of Components with higher indexes.

Please note that the first mechanism uses **Integer** and the second mechanism uses **int**. Also, one renders high values on top of low ones, and the other does the opposite. Do not mix the two :)

My question is: what's the point of using JLayeredPane when Container already provides the same mechanism? Does one layer components better than the another?

**UPDATE**: There is also [Container.setComponentZOrder(Component, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) to consider.

Comment: You could also use a Glass Pane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question:

[Container.add(Component, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) and [Container.setComponentZOrder(Component, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) are virtually identical. The former invokes removeNotify() while the latter does not (for performance reasons).

Container-layering only works if [JComponent.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled%28%29http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled%28%29) returns false. One implementation that just-so-happens to return false is... you guessed it: [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)

Using Container-layering is discouraged because it can have [unexpected side-effects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).

Finally, it is worth noting that while Container declares [add(Component, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) it doesn't actually paint layered components properly. [JComponent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and its subclasses do.

Another interesting find: never invoke repaint() on a child of JLayeredPane. This will cause the component to paint itself on top regardless of its z-order. You should only invoke repaint() on the JLayeredPane itself.

Comment: Re "never invoke repaint() on a child of JLayeredPane":  I'm curious about what type of child component you found this with.  I ran into [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668721/jmenuitems-painting-over-higher-components-in-jlayeredpane) and determined that, in my case at least, it was an issue with JMenuItems specifically. They behave as if they're always on top (unless they're transparent).

Comment: @Aaron, I don't remember which component I used but when you think about it it makes sense that all components will behave they are always on top. paint() is meant to assume that you will set the clip bounds to prevent it from drawing outside the desired bounds. When you invoking repaint() directly on a child component (with no bounds) you are essentially asking for it to ignore its parent. In other words, this isn't a bug in the Swing implementation. It's user error.

Comment: Actually that's not correct.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/), specifically the Paint Processing section. It states that when `repaint()` is called on a JComponent, the RepaintManager uses the clip rectangle and the component's `opaque` and `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled` properties to determine the 'root' component from which the paint operation must begin. Most components, in fact, do not behave as if they're always on top (i.e. `alwaysOnTop()` returns `false` by default).

Comment: @Aaron, good point! Unfortunately, I don't remember which component was misbehaving with repaint() so I can't verify what was going on.

Comment: You can [overwrite the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442322/java-repaint-hiding-other-panel) `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled` to return `false`. My understanding is that this enable container-layering in most JComponents, although there might be downsides for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is that the `Container.add(Component,int)` and the `JLayeredPane.add(Component,Integer)` functions set the component being added at a certain index. It is then this index that is used by layout managers to handle position, layout, and order of painting of the component. I think `JLayeredPane.setLayer(Component c, int layer)` is more what your looking for as far as layers go. It is specifically created to layer the components. Just my two sense.