# JMenuItems painting over higher components in JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane, jmenuitem

I have a set of JMenuItems in a JPanel on one layer of a JLayeredPane, and an emulated cursor painted in a JPanel on a higher layer.  When the menu items repaint, they paint over the emulated cursor (without triggering a repaint of the cursor layer). Interestingly, if I substitute JButtons or JLabels for the menu items, the cursor is correctly painted each time the menu items repaint.

**How can I ensure that repainting the menu items will cause the affected regions of the higher layers to repaint as well, without directly calling repaint() on the layered pane?**  The situation I've described is somewhat simplified from reality: the menu items may be deeply nested in a child of the layered pane, and they should not know about the layered pane at all.

Here's a snippet of pseudo-code illustrating what I've described:

```
public void initGui(Dimension size) {
   JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
   layeredPane.setSize(size);

   menuPanel = new JPanel();
   menuPanel.setSize(size);
   layeredPane.add(menuPanel, BOTTOM_LAYER);

   JPanel cursorPanel = new CursorPanel();
   cursorPanel.setSize(size);
   layeredPane.add(cursorPanel, TOP_LAYER);
}

public void showMenu(Component[] menuItems) {
   JPanel menu = new JPanel();
   for (Component c: menuItems)
      menu.add(c);
   menuPanel.add(menu);
}
```

Comment: OK but please specify what is the question. :) Plus code would be helpful to see all what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JComponent has a package-private `alwaysOnTop()` method that the Swing painting system uses to determine whether repainting a component may necessitate repainting other components.  By default this method returns `false`, but JMenuItem overrides it to return `true` unless the menu item appears in a JInternalFrame.  As a consequence, components that appear above a JMenuItem will *not* be repainted when the menu item is repainted (except when the menu item is in an internal frame).

Since `alwaysOnTop()` is package-private, it cannot be overridden in a custom component.  It seems that the only solutions are to

- use a different component (e.g. JButton, JLabel)
- place the menu in an internal frame
- make the components transparent (i.e. `setOpaque(false)`)

I ended up using the latter solution. Since I didn't actually want transparent menu items I wrapped the paint code with calls to set/clear the opaque property:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{ 
   // paint the component as opaque
   setOpaque(true);
   super.paintComponent(g);
   setOpaque(false);
}
```

Comment: +1 Good that you shared your solution to your problem with us. This is a solution I would go with.