# Java repaint hiding other panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have 3 Jpanels nested like the following:

```
main JPanel
{
  second JPanel {}
  3rd JPanel {}
  main method
}
```

This is the order I have added them in the 'main panel' :

```
    add(thirdPanel);
    add(secondPanel);
    setComponentZOrder(componentsPanel, 0);
    setComponentZOrder(panel, 1);
```

The second and third panels both have `paintComponent` methods and initially the thirdPanel which contains GUI components such as `buttons` etc. is on top of the secondPanel (which is what I want) but whenever I draw or `repaint` in the secondPanel, all the components in thirdPanel are hidden beneath the secondPanel. It's like secondPanel is taking priority. I basically want the thirdPanel to stay on top no matter what.

Note: I am using a null layout manager.

Comment: setComponentZOrder is done by LayoutManager, not required, btw whats is your question (based on description and code posted)

Comment: Sorry if Q was a little unclear. Q: How do I stop the secondPanel from overriding the components in thirdPanel everytime secondPanel draws/repaints?

Comment: *"I am using a null layout manager."*  If you look through the accepted answers of the [tag:null-layout-manager] questions, I'd wager that most, if not all of them, were solved by *using a layout manager.*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look at those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the [`isOptimizedDrawingEnabled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled--) method of the parent panel and have it return `false`:

```
@Override
public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

This is necessary if a component's children **overlap**, otherwise Swing will not paint them correctly.